# Oracle refresh materialized view - Compile error

Tags: oracle, plsql, materialized-views, ora-06550

Im trying to execute a refresh on a materialized view, but I cant get the script to compile.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MV AS
BEGIN
    exec DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('my_mat_view_mv','C');
END REFRESH_MV;
```

I get the message:

> ORA-06550: line 3, column 9:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol
>   "DBMS_MVIEW" when expecting one of the
>   following:
>
> := . ( @ % ; immediate The symbol
>   ":=" was substituted for "DBMS_MVIEW"
>   to continue.

Am i doing something wrong ? Need to import anything?

## Update

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MV AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE  DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('my_mat_view_mv','C');
END REFRESH_MV;
```

> (S1917) Expecting:    (    ;    @
>   IMMEDIATE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MV AS
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('my_mat_view_mv','C');
END REFRESH_MV;

Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

This is an Oracle 10g XE, hope thats no problem.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Im sure its one of those silly mistakes.

Comment: Try `EXECUTE DBMS_MVIEW...` instead of `EXEC DBMS_MVIEW...`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think if you just eliminate the "exec" altogether it might work better. "exec" is a SQL*Plus command. IOW, try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MV AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('my_mat_view_mv','C');
END REFRESH_MV;
```

Comment: Yes, thats the way i fixed it.
Thanks